# Is there anything that explains the expected behavior of a pre-checked RadioButton when it is added to a container with other checked RadioButtons?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

While attempting to debug a different issue in my code, I ran across something surprising. If I create some radio buttons and set them all to be checked and add them to a panel, they will all be checked. This may sound expected, if not for the natural exclusiveness of a radio button. The following code snippet (which can be run in LINQPad) demonstrates this behavior.

```
var radioButtons = new[]
{
    new RadioButton { Text = "Option 1", },
    new RadioButton { Text = "Option 2", },
    new RadioButton { Text = "Option 3", },
};

var panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
foreach (var radioButton in radioButtons)
{
    radioButton.Checked = true;
    panel.Controls.Add(radioButton);
    // radioButton.Checked = true;
}
panel.Dump();
```

As written, the output will be a panel containing all three radio buttons as checked. One interesting point is that because they are all checked, you cannot uncheck any of them via user input because it would require checking a unchecked radio button in the group (which there are none).

If you comment out the `Checked = true` line before adding the radio button to the panel and uncomment the same line after adding it to the panel then the whole thing behaves a little more in-line with what I'd expect. Each new radio button gets checked which unchecks the radio buttons already in the panel, leaving only the last one checked.

Is there any documentation anywhere that explains this behavior - or at least stating that this is the expected behavior? I looked through the remarks in the [RadioButton documentation online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) though nothing stood out.

Comment: If the Checked event occurs before adding it to the Panel, a determination cannot be made as to which radio buttons needs to be unchecked because the event did no occur within the Panel. But when set afterwards, the Checked event will fire within the Panel and produce the results you expect.

Comment: What is peculiar though, is when setting the first radio button to checked and then looping through all three in your array, you will see that all three radio buttons are checked. That could use some explanation.

Comment: You're asking it to add three checked radio buttons to the panel, and its doing exactly what you told it to. Once the button belongs to the panel, only then does the exclusivity rule get enforced. How else would you have it work?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RadioButton.cs,950ca0f28862a5a9,references  Some clues are given within the PerformAutoUpdates method.

Comment: @MikeG That's a good find, Of particular note is that it doesn't call `PerformAutoUpdates` when it's is set. I was just curious if this was called out anywhere in the documentation/specification.

Comment: @aldie_lab If it isn't specified anywhere, then adding a new RadioButton that is already checked could cause the other RadioButtons in the group to become unchecked. I find that getting put in the situation where all the RadioButtons can be checked and it becoming impossible to uncheck one of them via user input a very unfortunate result of this.

Comment: @Anthony If that situation did happen, that would mean there is a bug in the code. Your proposal is that the `RadioButtons` should auto-correct themselves, however whatever logic is used to do that might not be correct course of action. You could set `AutoCheck = false` and handle the check/uncheck logic in the `OnClick` event.